# Gulp throwing "pre-build test failed" errors at end of tasks execution

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm facing an issue with Gulp.
At the end of every Gulp task i'm having this error :

```
C:\dev\yo\backbone>gulp jshint
[12:03:09] Using gulpfile C:\dev\yo\backbone\gulpfile.js
[12:03:09] Starting 'jshint'...
C:\dev\yo\backbone\src\scripts\utils.js: line 3, col 30, Missing semicolon.

1 error
[12:03:11] Finished 'jshint' after 2.33 s
? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
? Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
? Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
? pre-build test failed, compiling from source...
? Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
? Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
libpng-dev is installed
```

It seems like some network operations are launched but I don't understand why since the task has finished.
I'm working with a corporate proxy server that must block these network operations.

Has anyone met the same problem ?
Is there any configuration to set ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allright so it's not gulp itself but gulp-imagemin that is throwing this error. I have removed this line in my gulpfile require('gulp-imagemin') and now it's working fine. Must be an installation problem with gulp-imagemin.

Answer (score 0):

The error message saids "Missing semicolon", did you checked that (add a semicolon) ?

```
 require('gulp-imagemin');
```